# Best way to implement public blockchain for IoT?

Tags: encryption, blockchain

I'm attempting to build a blockchain network of IoT devices that would allow public access such that any person around the world could push data to it and there would be an immutable record of all data pledged to the network. The validity of the data or the trust of the client isn't important, but keeping a permanent ledger of all activity is. Reducing centralization is also important for this particular application, hence the need for blockchain. What is the best way to go about creating such a system? What consensus algorithm is best for this application? Proof of work seems like overkill. Proof of stake? Would proof of authority be best?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is too broad, and I guess will be closed as such. Also the functional description 1) does not tell what kind of access must be possible for the data  2) does not address that if anyone can push data on something without some limitation mechanism, that opens to denial of service. It's already bad if the data is moved to /dev/null (lost), but gets much worse if it must be somewhat retrievable.